# Observable Pagination for infinite scroll to stay up to date

Tags: rxjs, pagination, observable, combinelatest, mergemap

I am trying to get my observable to update automatically during pagination.

**Only Page Trigger**

When `load()` is called, the page observable gets triggered, but the subscription observable does not get triggered when it is updated...

```js
pageSub = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);
page = 1;

// in constructor...

this.posts = this.pageSub
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((page: number) => this.urql
      .subscription(this.GET_POSTS,
        {
          first: this.ITEMS.toString(),
          offset: (this.ITEMS * (page - 1)).toString()
        }
      )
    ),
    scan((acc, value) => [...acc, ...value]),
  );

// called from button

load() {
  this.page += 1;
  this.pageSub.next(this.page);
}
```

**Only Subscription Trigger**

Here a subscription change does get triggered, but when `load()` is called, a page change does not get triggered...

```js
this.posts = combineLatest([this.pageSub, this.urql
  .subscription(this.GET_POSTS,
    {
      first: this.ITEMS.toString(),
      offset: (this.ITEMS * (this.page - 1)).toString()
    }
  )]).pipe(
    map((arr: any[]) => arr[1])
  );
```

Surely, there is a way so that the Observable gets updated with a page change and with a subscription change?

I should add that resetting the variable declaration `this.posts` does not work, as it refreshed the page and is not intended behavior.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

J

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz with small demo, because as far as i see your first solution should work. Can you show us what is behind ` this.urql`

Comment: If I call `load()` the first solution does work, however, it is technically a page observable not a combined observable, so the data does not get updated when the subscription changes, only when the page changes.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "subscription changes" and what is getting called when you refer `this.urql.subscrition(...)`

Comment: I have an external database.  Normally, if I update a database value, it will be updated immediately on the website  because the observable is a subscription to the database using websockets.  However, I want this to still work when using pagination.  The first example actually subscribes to the pagination change, but not to the database changes.  When a page change is triggered (by `pageSub.next()`), the page is updated.  However, when a database value is changed, it does not get updated on the website immediately. I want the observable triggered on a db value change, and on `pageSub.next()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```js
mainStream: BehaviorSubject<Observable<any>>;

posts!: Observable<any>;

constructor(private urql: UrqlModule) {

  this.mainStream = new BehaviorSubject<Observable<any>>(this.getPosts());

  this.posts = this.mainStream.pipe(mergeAll());

}

async load() {
  this.page += 1;
  this.mainStream.next(this.combine(this.mainStream.value, this.getPosts()));
}

getPosts() {
  return this.urql.subscription(this.GET_POSTS,
    {
      first: this.ITEMS.toString(),
      offset: (this.ITEMS * (this.page - 1)).toString()
    }
  )
}

combine(o: Observable<any>, o2: Observable<any>) {
  return combineLatest([o, o2]).pipe(
    map((arr: any) => arr.reduce((acc: any, cur: any) => acc.concat(cur)))
  );
}
```